How to increase logo space in header of WordPress Twentysixteen Theme?
I have a logo that is over 2000px wide, but when I place it as the logo in the top left of the theme header, it gets shrunk down to barely 200px. In the style.css file I found:
.custom-logo {
    max-width: 180px;
}

and I changed that to 400px and that didn't affect anything.
In the header.php file is the line:
<?php twentysixteen_the_custom_logo(); ?>

but I checked the functions.php and other files and I cannot find that function
However in the functions.php file on lines 74 - 86 is the function:
/*
         * Enable support for custom logo.
         *
         *  @since Twenty Sixteen 1.2
         */
        add_theme_support(
            'custom-logo',
            array(
                'height'      => 240,
                'width'       => 240,
                'flex-height' => true,
            )
        );

In that function I changed the width to 400 and that didn't change anything on the front.
Looking at the header, you can see there is plenty of room for a wider logo:

How can I get the logo image to fill the space up to the right nav?

EDIT 2024-06-07: Add details about the additional style definitions previously unmentioned in the original question and this answer
When you upload a custom logo using:
wp-admin > Appearance > Customize > Site Identity > Select Logo
... a new file will be created in the Media Library, cropped AND SCALED to the dimensions set when you selected the image.
This means that even if you selected the entire dimensions of the image in the cropping screen during selection, the image will still be scaled down to the maximum dimensions you saw in functions.php (i.e. your 2000+ px wide image becomes exactly 240 px and the height becomes whatever value less than 240 px maintains the original aspect ratio because of the 'flex-height' => true parameter).
Since that is now a new file within the Media Library, changing the max width of the .custom-logo class in the stylesheet will never make the image wider since it's actual widest physical dimension is 240px. Technically you could replace the "max-width" attribute with plain old "width" and let the CSS forcibly stretch the image to whatever width you set, but it will likely break aspect ratio and become pixelated when scaled up in one dimension.
What you need to do instead is change the functions.php (see warning at end of answer) to something like:
add_theme_support(
    'custom-logo',
    array(
        'height'      => 240,
        'width'       => 800,
        'flex-height' => true,
    )
);

Then, go to the theme customizer and reselect the originally uploaded image, recrop, and save. This will now create a new image in the Media Library that has an actual width of 800px. Note that you may also need to tinker with the height parameter in functions.php before doing this in order to get the full image into the crop and keep the aspect ratio.
Finally, the image will still display smaller than 800px wide when you view the front-end, but you can now adjust the max-width attribute in the stylesheet to let it display wider (up to whatever actual physical size it was scaled to by the parameters you set in functions.php). Note that the Twenty Sixteen theme's style.css has a total of three definitions which govern the size of the image. These are found at lines 1618, 2824, and 3469 at the time of writing this. The first is the base definition. The second and third apply when the site is loaded in a window with a minimum display width of >=710px and >=985px respectively. You'll need to experiment with what values work best for each of these cases, particularly the base definition which will apply when the site is rendered in mobile.
P.S. - There are more parameters for the functions.php snippet that may help you achieve the exact look you want (https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/custom-logo/)
P.P.S. - The function twentysixteen_the_custom_logo() is found in the file wp-content\themes\twentysixteen\inc\template-tags.php (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/314449/using-themename-the-custom-logo-in-template-tags) but doesn't help much in the context of your question.
Standard but crucial reminder:
Don't edit default theme files or they will be overwritten and you will lose your changes if the theme is updated. Instead use child themes (https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/).

Thank you for your answer. I tried your solution. After reading the "Standard but crucial reminder" I decided to edit the default theme files to see if it worked before actually creating a child theme. I was not successful with your handling. I believe I did it in the right sequence, but it continues to constrain the logo to 240 px on the display. Is there possibly some other setting that hasn't been addressed?

Please verify: 1) After changing the width attribute from 240px to a higher value in functions.php, refresh the theme customizer page. 2) When using the theme customizer to select a new logo in the Site Identity section, do the dimensions you entered in functions.php appear in the recommended image size message? 3) Search styles.css for more references to the .custom-image class. There are three which affect the size of the image near lines: 1618, 2823, 3469. Change these all to a higher value. I suspect point 3 is the culprit since neither of us mentioned the other CSS definitions previously.

Bingo! The other settings for .custom-logo in styles.css made the difference. 800 was too wide and it eventually ended up at 550. Thanks for your help!

Thanks for marking my answer as accepted and helping me build rep! I'm glad you got this working, and would suggest you experiment with the three values in the stylesheet to get the best results when the site is scaled in different width browser windows. I've edited my original answer to include references to the 3 stylesheet definitions and how they apply to governing the image size. Cheers!
